# d????????? "cannot access (dirname): No such device"

Tags: 14.04, directory, nfs

A server (running 14 LTS) that I admin had an NFS mount (which I will call "FooFolder") previously set up by another admin (who is not available). The mount broke during some changes on the host server. The host is now working properly again. When I go into the /mnt directory, the remnant left behind by the old mount puzzles me:

```
foobar@fooserver:/mnt$ ls -al
ls: cannot access FooFolder: No such device
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct  7 18:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Oct 13 17:07 ..
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? FooFolder
foobar@fooserver:/mnt$ sudo mv FooFolder FooFolderOld
mv: cannot stat `FooFolder': No such device
foobar@fooserver:/mnt$ sudo chmod 775 FooFolder
chmod: cannot access `FooFolder': No such device
```

What is this thing that does not exist and cannot be accessed? And what should I do to remove it?

Comment: Have you tried to restart `nfsd` on the host and then re-mount? I had a similar situation with CIFS the other day...

Comment: Directories for some reason I can;t remember need to be executable to work *(learnt from being a idiot with `chmod`)* - if you unmount the share then make the directory executable as shown [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too) it *might* help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes asking a question out loud (and hearing responses) lets one rethink a problem more clearly. Hence, some refocused Google searching revealed an answer: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ls-shows-directory-attributes-as-question-marks-942157/

Those are the symptoms of a failed attempt to mount a CIFS share. umount clears the problem and allows it to be properly remounted.

Answer (score 0):

Unmount and remount it.. Simple
To un-mount run command 
umount 
for remount u can run
mount -a
(note that u must have entry in fstab file for this command. The entries are like this 
                   cifs 
and fstab file location is usually /etc/fstab)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  How is this answer different from the already existing answer?  **:/**